# Granting cloudtrails access to kms keys in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-kms

My first attempt at doing this resulted in a circular reference:

```
resource "aws_kms_key" "cloudtrails-key" {
  description = "KMS Master Key for trails logs"
  key_usage = "ENCRYPT_DECRYPT"
  customer_master_key_spec = "SYMMETRIC_DEFAULT"
  deletion_window_in_days = 30
  is_enabled = true
  enable_key_rotation = false
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.cloudtrails-key-policy.json
  multi_region = true
  
  tags = {
    ManagedBy                     = "terraform"
    Name                          = "${var.project_name}-${var.environment}-${var.aws_account_id}-cloudtrails-key"
    Environment                   = var.environment
    Usage                         = "monitoring"
  }
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "cloudtrails-key-policy" {
  statement {
    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = [ "cloudtrail.amazonaws.com" ]
    }

    actions = [
      "kms:CallerAccount",
      "kms:EncryptionAlgorithm",
      "kms:EncryptionContext:*",
      "kms:EncryptionContextKeys",
      "kms:RequestAlias",
      "kms:ViaService"
    ]

    resources = [ aws_kms_key.cloudtrails-key.arn ]

    condition {
     test     = "ForAnyValue:StringLike"
     variable = "aws:SourceArn"
     values   = toset([for k, v in var.all_account_ids : "arn:aws:cloudtrail:*:${v}:trail/full-cloudtrails"])
    }
  }
}
```

As I couldn't determine how to remove the circular reference, I decided to try using grants instead:

```
resource "aws_kms_grant" "cloudtrails-key-grant" {
  depends_on = [ aws_kms_key.cloudtrails-key ]
  for_each = var.all_account_ids
  name = "${each.key}-cloudtrails-key-grant"
  key_id = aws_kms_key.cloudtrails-key.key_id
  grantee_principal = "arn:aws:cloudtrail::${each.value}:trail/full-cloudtrails"
  operations = [ "Encrypt" ]
}
```

var.all_account_ids refers to a map of account names and account IDs.

I then updated the aws_kms_key block to remove the policy argument. However, this resulted instead in the following output on apply:

```
Terraform v1.3.8
on linux_amd64
aws_kms_grant.cloudtrails-key-grant["users"]: Creating...
aws_kms_grant.cloudtrails-key-grant["root"]: Creating...
aws_kms_grant.cloudtrails-key-grant["dev"]: Creating...
aws_kms_grant.cloudtrails-key-grant["shared"]: Creating...
aws_kms_grant.cloudtrails-key-grant["monitoring"]: Creating...
aws_cloudtrail.full-cloudtrails: Modifying... [id=full-cloudtrails]

...

aws_kms_grant.cloudtrails-key-grant["users"]: Still creating... [2m50s elapsed]
aws_kms_grant.cloudtrails-key-grant["monitoring"]: Still creating... [2m50s elapsed]
╷
│ Error: updating CloudTrail Trail (full-cloudtrails): InsufficientEncryptionPolicyException: Insufficient permissions to access S3 bucket full-cloudtrails or KMS key arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:703617067304:key/mrk-c0a4616ba4f74ae9b5ac4ecd1f96e95b.
│ 
│   with aws_cloudtrail.full-cloudtrails,
│   on monitoring.tf line 1, in resource "aws_cloudtrail" "full-cloudtrails":
│    1: resource "aws_cloudtrail" "full-cloudtrails" {
│ 
╵
╷
│ Error: creating KMS Grant for Key (mrk-c0a4616ba4f74ae9b5ac4ecd1f96e95b): InvalidArnException: ARN is not valid: arn:aws:cloudtrail:us-east-1:323924548037:trail/full-cloudtrails
│ 
│   with aws_kms_grant.cloudtrails-key-grant["root"],
│   on security.tf line 19, in resource "aws_kms_grant" "cloudtrails-key-grant":
│   19: resource "aws_kms_grant" "cloudtrails-key-grant" {
│ 
╵
╷
│ Error: creating KMS Grant for Key (mrk-c0a4616ba4f74ae9b5ac4ecd1f96e95b): InvalidArnException: ARN is not valid: arn:aws:cloudtrail:us-east-1:739800733271:trail/full-cloudtrails
│ 
│   with aws_kms_grant.cloudtrails-key-grant["shared"],
│   on security.tf line 19, in resource "aws_kms_grant" "cloudtrails-key-grant":
│   19: resource "aws_kms_grant" "cloudtrails-key-grant" {
│ 
╵
╷
│ Error: creating KMS Grant for Key (mrk-c0a4616ba4f74ae9b5ac4ecd1f96e95b): InvalidArnException: ARN is not valid: arn:aws:cloudtrail:us-east-1:703617067304:trail/full-cloudtrails
│ 
│   with aws_kms_grant.cloudtrails-key-grant["monitoring"],
│   on security.tf line 19, in resource "aws_kms_grant" "cloudtrails-key-grant":
│   19: resource "aws_kms_grant" "cloudtrails-key-grant" {
│ 
╵
╷
│ Error: creating KMS Grant for Key (mrk-c0a4616ba4f74ae9b5ac4ecd1f96e95b): InvalidArnException: ARN is not valid: arn:aws:cloudtrail:us-east-1:457407591303:trail/full-cloudtrails
│ 
│   with aws_kms_grant.cloudtrails-key-grant["dev"],
│   on security.tf line 19, in resource "aws_kms_grant" "cloudtrails-key-grant":
│   19: resource "aws_kms_grant" "cloudtrails-key-grant" {
│ 
╵
╷
│ Error: creating KMS Grant for Key (mrk-c0a4616ba4f74ae9b5ac4ecd1f96e95b): InvalidArnException: ARN is not valid: arn:aws:cloudtrail:us-east-1:158889104371:trail/full-cloudtrails
│ 
│   with aws_kms_grant.cloudtrails-key-grant["users"],
│   on security.tf line 19, in resource "aws_kms_grant" "cloudtrails-key-grant":
│   19: resource "aws_kms_grant" "cloudtrails-key-grant" {
│ 
╵
```

I tried adding the region (though I would prefer multi-region), taking off the trail name after the slash, using wildcards for region, but everything resulted in the above invalid ARN exception.

I was curious to know if anyone has any working recipes for granting cloudtrails encryption access to a KMS key, as I'm unsure what I'm doing wrong with either method (policy or grant)

Comment: I think you need both key policy and key grant. One allows a key to be used by a principal and the other one allows the principal to perform certain KMS actions. Additionally, I don't think that CloudTrail is a valid principal.

Comment: @marko-e I think you're right, since documentation states that all keys must have a policy attached. I managed to get the policy in by commenting out the assignment of the policy in the aws_kms_key block, but the second I uncomment, the cycle error re-appears.

A similar set up was required for s3 as well (bucket accessible from multi-account cloudtrails), but I don't get a cycle error due to the fact that the configuration had an aws_s3_bucket_policy I could attach the iam policy to. We don't have something like that for kms, but maybe one should be added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for the cyclical reference was to broaden the resource scope to all keys, and not just the one key. This was done on all examples in AWS documentation. I also had to add the default key policy offered by AWS otherwise I got a warning that I would be locking myself out.

The Default Key Policy can be found documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/key-policy-default.html). The specific key policy required for CloudTrail is found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/create-kms-key-policy-for-cloudtrail.html). Using these two resources, the final working configuration is below:

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "cloudtrail-key-policy" {
  statement {
    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = [ "cloudtrail.amazonaws.com" ]
    }

    actions = [
      "kms:DescribeKey",
      "kms:GenerateDataKey*"
    ]

    resources = [ "*" ]

    condition {
      test      = "ForAnyValue:StringLike"
      variable  = "kms:EncryptionContext:aws:cloudtrail:arn"
      values    = toset([for k, v in var.all_account_ids : "arn:aws:cloudtrail:*:${v}:trail/${k}-full-cloudtrail"])
    }

    condition {
      test      = "ForAnyValue:StringLike"
      variable  = "aws:SourceArn"
      values    = toset([for k, v in var.all_account_ids : "arn:aws:cloudtrail:*:${v}:trail/${k}-full-cloudtrail"])
    }
  }

  statement {
    principals {
      type        = "AWS"
      identifiers = [ "arn:aws:iam::${var.aws_account_id}:role/terraform-${var.environment}" ]
    }

    actions = [
      "kms:Create*",
      "kms:Describe*",
      "kms:Enable*",
      "kms:List*",
      "kms:Put*",
      "kms:Update*",
      "kms:Revoke*",
      "kms:Disable*",
      "kms:Get*",
      "kms:Delete*",
      "kms:TagResource",
      "kms:UntagResource",
      "kms:ScheduleKeyDeletion",
      "kms:CancelKeyDeletion"
    ]

    resources = [ "*" ]
  }

  statement {
    principals {
      type        = "AWS"
      identifiers = [ "arn:aws:iam::${var.aws_account_id}:root" ]
    }

    actions = [ "kms:*" ]
    resources = [ "*" ]
  }
}
```

Additionally, no grants were needed as we're doing this for a service. According to the documentation, service ARNs are excluded:

> The grantee principal can be any AWS principal, including an AWS
> account (root), an IAM user, an IAM role, a federated role or user, or
> an assumed role user. The grantee principal can be in the same account
> as the KMS key or a different account. However, the grantee principal
> cannot be a service principal, an IAM group, or an AWS organization

The above text can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/grants.html)

Hopefully this helps future readers with the same issue.

EDIT: Updated with final working config